# Java Anagrams reading from dictionary file

Tags: java, arrays, anagram

I am having trouble comparing my dictionary file to the anagrams. I put a print statement at each and it is reading in the dictionary file correctly and it is also calculating all of the anagrams correctly But it won't calculate only the anagrams from the dictionary file. I'm pretty sure it's something very minor and if someone can fix it it would greatly be appreciated.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Anagram3 
{
  static int size;
  static int count;
  static char[] charArray;
  static char[] words;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Type the path of the dictionary to read from : ");
String fileName = sc.nextLine();

List<String> dictionary = new ArrayList<String>();

BufferedReader br = null;     

try
{
  br = new  BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
  String word;

  while((word = br.readLine())!=null)
  {
      dictionary.add(word);
  }

}
catch(IOException e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
String[] words = new String[dictionary.size()];
dictionary.toArray(words);

//for( int i = 0; i < words.length; i++ )
//    System.out.println(words[i]);


System.out.println("\nEnter the phrase to scramble: ");
String input = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println();


    size = input.length();
    count = 0;
    charArray = new char[size];
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
      charArray[j] = input.charAt(j);
    doAnagram(size);
 }

public static void doAnagram(int newSize) 
{
 int limit;
if (newSize == 1) // if too small, return;
  return;
// for each position,
for (int i = 0; i < newSize; i++) {
  doAnagram(newSize - 1); // anagram remaining
  if (newSize == 2) // if innermost,
    printAnagrams(); 
  rotate(newSize); // rotate word
}
}


public static void rotate(int newSize) 
{
int i;
int position = size - newSize;

char temp = charArray[position];

for (i = position + 1; i < size; i++)
  charArray[i - 1] = charArray[i];

charArray[i - 1] = temp;
}

public static void printAnagrams() 
{
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{    
  //System.out.print(charArray[i]);
    if(charArray[i] == words[i])
    {
        System.out.print(charArray[i]);
    }

 }
 System.out.println();
}
}
```

Comment: (1) Please review the pasted code, it looks funny in the middle. (2) Do you ever check that the permutations you generate are found in the dictionary?

Comment: Yes that's what I do in the printAnnagrams() statement with the if statement and that is what I am having trouble with. and sorry this is my first time to do this what looks funny in the middle?

Comment: Hmm, `if(charArray[i] == words[i])` shouldn't even compile, comparing a `char` to a `String`. If it compiles, it should never evaluate to `true`.

Comment: Ok. I converted the string to a char and it still doesn't work.

Comment: No reason it wouldn't compile; you can check for equality between any two objects.

Comment: Ah, blast, forgot about autoboxing. Haven't done Java for a while.

Comment: @user1022969 -- if this is homework, it should be tagged as such.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your static variable words is not being used because you define a new String[] words before the assignment.
2. Use the equals method to compare Strings. [1](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/comparestrings.html)

Answer (score 0):

Another issue is that you're comparing the i'th anagram generated to the i'th element in your dictionary, when you actually (presumably) want to test if the i'th anagram is present in the dictionary at any position.

You can try using a HashSet h of strings, rather than the array, for the dictionary, and then check for validity of an anagram with h.contains(...).